# woocommerce get product id when product is add to cart

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hook

I need to do extra step in the backend when a product is add to cart.
I need to get the product ID juste after it's add to the cart.

I use the woocommerce hook woocommerce_add_to_cart

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'attach_item');

function attach_item() {
    // I need to have the product id here.
}
```

I tried many way to get the ID but nothing work.
Any idea ...

Comment: try `echo $product_id` in the action  `attach_item()`

Answer (score 2):

Today I also get the same problem but I got the solution.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart',10,2 );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data,$productId ) {
    var_dump($productId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, the hook is actually called from WooCommerce like so: ([source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/5.8/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1276))

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
```

Add your custom method like so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', function($cartItemKey, $productId) {
  // do sth with $productId
}, 10, 2);
```